# Get weights of a graph from different process

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I create multiple copies of a master model , each in a different process in order to get the gradients of each separately and apply them all to the master model en masse. (I'm testing it with only one child process for now (worker):

```
num_workers = 1
    master = ACNetwork()  # Creates the network
    envs = [gym.make('CartPole-v0') for i in range(num_workers)] 
    # the environment that gives me data to train on
    workers = [Worker(number=i, environment=envs[i], master_network=master,
                      counter=counter) for i in range(num_workers)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
```

My problem is that I create the master model in the parent process, pass it as an argument to every child process and getting the weights raises a value error :

```
# The worker executes
def run(self):
        with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
            self.private_net = ACNetwork()
.......
            a_grads, c_grads = self.private_net.get_gradients()
            self.master.update_from_gradients(a_grads, c_grads)
```

```
# now inside the master network
def update_from_gradients(self, actor_gradients, critic_gradients):
        grads_and_vars = list(zip(actor_gradients, self.actor_t.get_weights()))  
        # get_weights raises the error
        train_op = self.actor_opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

raises:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/kernel:0", shape=(4, 512), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph
```

From my understanding the code of updating weights is executed inside a graph that doesn't entail the master network thus raising the error. How can I preserve the master network's graph so that I can update it in the context of the child process?

Answer (score 0):

You must create the model in each of the processes and set equal weights, and keep the models there without closing the processes. You will need to control the train flow between them, making the processes wait for the main thread and vice-versa. This is probably way too hard and there are other options.

You don't need processes to pass parallel batches, you can make a parallel model:

```
mainModel = ....

inputs = []
outputs = []
for i in range(num_workers):
    inp = Input(input_shape)
    out = mainModel(inp)
    inputs.append(inp)
    outputs.append(out)

parallelModel = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Train with `num_workers` different groups of data:

```
parallelModel.fit(
               [xTrain1, xTrain2,...],
               [yTrain1, yTrain2,...]
               )
```

If you are using eager execution, even without a parallel model or other processes, you can pass `num_workers` batches, calculate their gradients, sum their gradients and finally apply gradients.

If you really want to use parallel processing without creating the suggested parallel model, you should probably use `multiprocessing.dummy` and keep one single model in the main thread, using the workers only to pass data and get gradients.

Now, even simpler, using a batch size that is `num_workers` times the size of each of your parallel batches will result in the same thing.

Comment: Hey daniel. If I understand correctly what you are saying then there is a problem in that your fit is done sequentially, only the gathering of the data is done parallely. In my description , gathering data and computing gradients is done parallely. It is the application of the gradients that is done synchronously. Basically I can't use .fit() at all, unless you are implying something different in which case please correct me

Comment: The first example in my answer processes 4 parallel batches in the same model. The resulting gradients is the same as the sum of 4 parallel different gradient calculations with those batches.

Comment: Oh now I get what you meant. It's a great answer but it's still not asynchronous. Suppose one thread finishes gathering data, I have to wait for all to finish to call one fit, because I don't think can I call .fit() on the same model from different threads. Of course the time interval between two threads finishing gathering data will not be much , presumably for now. But still...